# ifstream arguments - C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I Declared: `std::string input_file="1.txt";`
then I tried to do this command:

```
static ifstream myfile (input_file);
```

and I get the error: no matching function for call to : `std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)`

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: I don't believe you can't tell what an appropriate answer would be. Sure, he should take the time to actually phrase the question, but please save your kind of comment to the cases where it is difficult to understand what the question is, not merely where the asker has forgotten to pose the question explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: @Magnus, the question might have been about what to do instead, as you apparently correctly guessed, but it might also have been about why the class doesn't have the expected constructor in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
static ifstream myfile(input_file.c_str());
```

For some reason, the `ifstream` constructor doesn't accept an `std::string`.

Comment: Note that in C++11, all file streams **do** now have a constructor overload taking a `std::string const&`.